# Is it possible to use MongoDB as a substitude for MySQL in a particular scenario?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, backend

I am participating in an project that using MongoDB as the datasorce instead of MySQL. The project is an APP for live-streaming with large amount of data and frequent IO. I am not sure if MongoDB is better than MySQL in this scenario.

Comment: “.. in *a* particular scenario ..” trivially, yes. Is that suited to *this* scenario? More information needed to offer any reasonable advice. It’s also possible to mix different data layers depending on needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely no. MongoDB would excel in cases where you have hierarchical data in several levels and an arbitrary structure. If your data falls naturally into columns and tables then MySQL would likely trounce MongoDB.

Comment: What does "arbitrary structrue" mean?

Comment: @koko When basically you don't have a schema or a format for the data. If you can represent anything as a well formed JSON file, you can push into MongoDB.